# Phonegap Build process for development

Tags: javascript, html, mobile, cordova

There is so much conflicting information out there on this, I'm hoping we can shed some light.

Goal: Create and develop a phonegap app that will be built using phonegap build.

1) I don't want to install the android and iOS SDKs, that's why I want to use phonegap build.

2) I created an app using the cordova cli `cordova create hello`

3) There is no phonegap.js or cordova.js I guess because I didn't add a platform. But I don't want to add a platform as that requires installing the SDKs

4) I need to be able to debug and test this, so I downloaded ripple, which may or may not work, I need the phonegap.js file first to see.

So has anyone figured this out? Building and developing and app that will be used on Phonegap build?

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you need Ripple when PhoneGap Build already lets you debug the app remotely

Comment: So I don't have to build it every time I make a change.

Answer (score 0):

Phonegap will let you create a UI using webview of Android, iOS, Blackberry or other platforms. That means you need to have native SDK to apply Phonegap Build. It doesn't mean that Phonegap will create an App for you and deploy it to other platforms.

Comment: Quoted in their video and on their page that they take the SDKs out of the picture. They specifically say you don't need the SDKs as that's the point of phonegap build, hence this stack question.